# How is transactionIndex decided in a block?

Tags: web3js, transactions, web3.py

I'm using web3py and web3js to send transactions on the Harmony EVM chain using `sendRawTransaction`, and i noticed that once my transaction is sent, the `transactionIndex` value will always be between `0` and `3`. Why is that? And is there a way to set a specific index for my transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transactionIndex will be set by miner. each block has many transactions which are ordered to mine. your transaction's index is 0 when the block goes to mine the transaction was first tx in that block. maybe you are using local dev node because in real networks a user cant get his/her tx all the time at first place in a block

Comment: It's not always 0, but it's always a low number between 0 and 3. Here is an example https://explorer.harmony.one/tx/0x1852ba3fac03d7e02529fc7d4da53301610410ae3d96740beefe47f3c2063b17

Comment: it's about gas price, miners will mine those txs with higher gas price first, at your block, your gas price was 0.00000405 then you reached 2 index, 0 index had more gas price: 0.0000054 and 4 index has lower than gas price as you : 0.00000002

Comment: Damn i didn't notice that. Thank you a lot!